# divide csv file results by month

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
Date,Fruits,buy,sell
09/08/2019,apples,8,3
10/08/2019,oranges,10,6
10/08/2019,bananas,1,2
10/08/2019,kiwi,7,2
....
26/10/2020,pineapple,4,2
26/10/2020,watermelon,8,7
26/10/2020,grape,8,2
28/10/2020,apples,2,5
28/10/2020,oranges,6,1
```

i made a simple code to give me the number of days with profit or non profit for all dates.

```
file = csv.reader(open('csvfile.csv'))
next(file)

profit = 0
non_profit = 0
days = 0

for day in file:
    days += 1
    buy = int(day[2])
    sell = int(day[3])

    if buy < sell:
        profit += 1
    else:
        non_profit += 1

print('In', (days), 'days , you have profit in', (profit), 'days, and', (non_profit), 'non profit days ')
```

I need help to find profit and non profit days, by month.
Thanks.

Comment: Please tag this with the code language you are using so people can find the question :)

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?  For one thing it looks like you are incrementing your `days` count for each line of the csv file, while the csv file appears to have more than one record for each day.

Answer (score 0):

For that [comprehension lists](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) do almost all the job.
First you split all days into 2 list of profit and non profit days, then you create new lists with number of month only which make it easier in next to count days in month which were profit/nonprofit. Later you go through list of months and create tuple of month number and profit/nonprofit days in certain month. At the end you can convert list into dictionary for easier use later in the code.

```
import csv

file = csv.reader(open('test.txt'))
next(file)

#Get all lines/days from file
days = [day for day in file]

#Create list with profit and non profit days
days_profit = [d[0] for d in days if int(d[2]) < int(d[3])]
days_nonprofit = [d[0] for d in days if int(d[2]) > int(d[3])]

#Create list with month numbers only
m_p = [d.split('/')[1] for d in days_profit]
m_np = [d.split('/')[1] for d in days_nonprofit]

#Create list of tuples with month number and days in month which were profit/nonprofit
profit_days_per_month     = [(int(m), m_p.count(m)) for m in set(m_p)]
non_profit_days_per_month = [(int(m), m_np.count(m)) for m in set(m_np)]

#Additionally for future use you can convert it to dictionaries
profit_days_dict = dict(profit_days_per_month)
nonprofit_days_dict = dict(non_profit_days_per_month)

print(profit_days_dict)
print(nonprofit_days_dict)
```